# Having String messages in a different class

Tags: java

I am going to have a lot of String text in my application. Therefore i thought to have all these Strings in 1 class. So that it would be easy to go and modify a String if there's a requirement to.

```
public class MyMessage {

static final String NAME = "JOE";
static final String AGE = "21";
......

}
```

And then access it in other classes like `MyMessage.NAME` and `MyMessage.AGE`.

1.) Is this approach correct ?

2.) I also found that, we could use property files to do so. Is this true? (And what is the best approach to do this `property file` or `having static methods in a java class`)

Comment: your approach is absolutely fine!

Comment: That's a valid approach, but your constants should be `public`.  Also, a more appropriate approach would be to have constants in the class they logically correspond to.

Comment: Then it would be messy. I will have various classes, and it would be a hassle to go and find these classes and edit

Comment: @invariant Other's disagree with my approach. What are your comments on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use property files, and typically this is a better approach. Aside from anything else, this allows you to pick up different resources for different languages. See the documentation for [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and [`PropertyResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) for more information.

You may still want to have a type to maintain the resource bundle keys, but personally I'd make that an enum rather than constants in a class.

Comment: So i have to read from a property file and populate the variable is it ?

Comment: @sharonHwk: You use `PropertyResourceBundle` to load the appropriate property file based on locale. You then look up the right string based on an appropriate key. As I say, I'd use an enum for the resource keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change value of any constant in your constant class file you will have to recompile the class. But you don't need to do it when you using properties file. So properties file is  better option.

Comment: But, then again i will have to read the property class from a Java code right? Does that mean i have to initially read the property file and save the key-value pair in variables in another class ?

Comment: No, you don't need to store values in java file after reading from properties file. Whenever you need a value just read it from property file. Consider property file as permanent storage of your key values pairs; so read it only when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little what you really want to achieve. Do you want it to be easy for you to add new strings without modifying the source code of the program? Do you want to support multiple languages? It depends what your actual situation is.

Apart from what you suggested, a popular approach is to use Resource Bundles. These are essentially used to group strings and make it easier for you to edit them. Another feature they support (you might not need this) is having multiple languages, i.e. a different resource bundle for each language you want to support. The actual strings are held in property files.

This is a good tutorial: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file-with-a-resource-bundle.html

Answer (score 1):

> @invariant Other's disagree with my approach. What are your comments
>   on this ?

well it depends on how often you change those values ,Let me explain with one example,In my application i have to work with state names of US  in many classes for this purpose i prefer to create a class

```
public class Juridictions {
public static final String OH = "OH";
public static final String CA = "CA";
..

}
   //when ever i need
   if(localvalue.equals(Juridictions.CA) {
   system.out.println("you are from CA !");
}
```

using properties file approach for this use case(i believe state names don't change!)  is  **Premature Optimization** (because it requires more code to read from file then using values when ever you need than above approach)

If you're not sure about how often you change your values , then follow **when in doubt leave it out** ,